# How to update Springboot application to use SSL/TLS certificates to connect to RDS?

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, amazon-rds

I am using Amazon RDS MySQL as the primary database. As per this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-rds-customers-update-your-ssl-tls-certificates-by-february-5-2020/), I am required to update the application to use the new CAs. I am following [this instruction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/ssl-certificate-rotation-mysql.html) proved by AWS to update my application.

The following specific instruction is not very clear:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path_to_truststore/MyTruststore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=my_truststore_password com.companyName.MyApplication
```

Even after the update, the application fails to start with the following error message:

```
2021-05-08 22:30:15org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
2021-05-08 22:30:15Unable to obtain connection from database: Communications link failure
2021-05-08 22:30:15The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2021-05-08 22:30:15--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-05-08 22:30:15SQL State : 08S01
2021-05-08 22:30:15Error Code : 0
2021-05-08 22:30:152021-05-08 12:30:15.312 INFO 6 --- [ main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
```

My application is running in Fargate platform version 1.3.0.

Application Dockerfile (simplified):

```
FROM openjdk:11

ARG JAR_PATH


RUN curl -k https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem -o rds-ca-2019-root.pem
RUN openssl x509 -outform der -in rds-ca-2019-root.pem -out rds-ca-2019-root.der
RUN echo yes | keytool -import -alias rds-root -keystore clientkeystore.jks -storepass changeme -file rds-ca-2019-root.der

RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR app

RUN mkdir config

COPY $JAR_PATH app.jar

CMD java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/clientkeystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeme -jar app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
```

I am using `clientStore.jks` as the `trustStore` value in the `java` command. I am not entirely sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone needs this now but I recently had to do this and was able to make it work by setting up keystore and configuring my connection string as

```
jdbc:mysql://DB_HOST:DB_PORT/DATABASE?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&sslMode=VERIFY_IDENTITY&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:/rds-truststore.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=changeit
```

You can find more details here: https://medium.com/@akoolshrestha/connecting-to-rds-mysql-via-ssl-tls-with-springboot-in-a-docker-container-443a3934bda2